# Best way to store non-observable data in a React Stateless Component (with Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx-react

I'm using mobx-react / mobx-react-lite for state management

Using classes i can define a non observable idToDelete to store the clicked item id, open a Modal using an observable and when the user clicks "Delete", i know the item to delete. The id is "remembered" by the component trough the re-renders

```
    class Greeting extends React.Component {
      idToDelete = null;

      confirmDelete = id => {
        this.idToDelete = id;
        openConfirm = true;
      }

      closeModal = () => {
        openConfirm = true;
        this.idToDelete = null;
      }

      @observable
      openConfirm = false;
      render() {
        // List of items with delete button
        <button onClick=this.confirmDelete(id)>Delete</button>

        // Confirm Delete Modal

      }
    }
```

But in a stateless component the id will become null (the initialization value) on each re-render.

Using [useLocalStore](https://mobx-react.netlify.com/state-local) hook i can store observable values:

> All properties of the returned object will be made observable
>   automatically

But i dont want to re-render just because i am storing/changing the id.

Using React.React.createContext / useContext seems like a bit overkill to me (it's kind of private value and it is not relevant outside the component itself)

Is there a "local storage" way to achieve this? (without observable convertion)

What are best practices for this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook to save the value. A change to this value will not trigger a re-render and the value will remain the same across renders unless you override it.

Its also explained in detail [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables)

> Yes! The useRef() Hook isn’t just for DOM refs. The “ref” object is a
>   generic container whose current property is mutable and can hold any
>   value, similar to an instance property on a class.

eg:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

const idToDelete = useRef("");

confirmDelete = id => {
    idToDelete.current = id;
}

closeModal = () => {
    idToDelete.current = null;
}
```

Also mind the catch, you need to use `.current` to access the data.